# Преобразование из инфиксной нотации

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Задание написать грубо говоря калькулятор простой с операциями (+,-,*,/,^), по методу [Эдсгер Дейкстра](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) я превратил выражение  3 + 4 * 2 / (1 - 5)^2 в 3 4 2 * 1 5 - 2 ^ / +
с этим я разобрался,но вопрос в том как теперь это предложение посчитать ?? Что дальше с ним делать все не как не догоняю(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перебираете полученные элементы. Если операнд (число), то кладете его в стек. Если операция, то выполняете ее над **вершиной и подвершиной** стека (удаляя их из стека), а результат кладете в стек (он становится вершиной).

Если выражение было сбалансированным, то его результат (когда все элементы закончатся) будет на вершине стека, а стек будет из одного элемента.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное)))) Я так и делал но была оказывается загвоздка в том что не правильно определялись приоритеты операций)) с вашей помощью я решил еще раз попробовать и нашел ошибку)) еще раз спасибо)) сидел долго над этой проблемой приятно было решить))